# Video Playback Stutters

Tags: macos, video

I am on a 2017 MacBook Air, Intel i3, 8GB RAM, I am on Big Sur 11.5.1 and every video, including the video previews for trackpad gestures are stuttering. I have done virus scans with Malwarebytes and it found nothing. YouTube and downloaded content is slow, please help.

Comment: If Internet access is slow in general: Does a reboot of both your MBA and your router change things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Activity Monitor to check if there's something using an excessive amount of your CPU:

1. Open `Activity Monitor.app`. You can find it via Spotlight or in `/System/Applications/Utilities`.
2. At the top of the window, click the `CPU` tab.
3. In the menu bar, click `View > All Processes`.
4. Click on the `% CPU` column header to order the list by current CPU usage.

If a specific app is using a lot of CPU (around 100% or more), try quitting it. If it doesn't respond, try force quitting by selecting it in the list and clicking the `Stop` button in the toolbar.

Comment: Thanks, an Adobe program was hogging all my CPU.